# Plus operator is appending instead of doing math

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript when I run this code:

```
parent.css("top") + parent.height() * 2
```

The result in Chrome console is:

> 100px320

Why is this happening?
`parent.height()` equals 160, so it seems like `parent.css("top")` is a string and JS is simply adding some characters to a string instead of doing math calculations.

Why is it not working and how do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the string to a number - you can use `parseInt` to do this:

```
parseInt(parent.css("top"),10) + parent.height() * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator is "overloaded" in Javascript.

Really what's happening is there's no **typing** in Javascript, so the `+` operator is attempting to coerce your values to be `+`-able.

You're right that `.css("top")` is a string: the `.css` method will return exactly what's in the CSS, and you'd better have unit declarations in your CSS.

When Javascript encounters `+` between two variables of different types, it does the best it can, and coerces the integer to a string so you don't lose any precision.

You could do something like this to fix it:

```
parseInt( parent.css( "top" ) ) - - parent.height() * 2;
```

This has two catches:

1. parseInt takes the first integer is sees and returns that. `100px` will return `100` **but so will 100,400**.  Be careful.
2. `- -` will force Javascript to do arithmetic, since you're asking it to subtract a number from a negative number, which is the same as addition. However, there's no ambiguity with the `-` operator, so it will either work or produce `NaN`.